# Did I lose content after I got the writing cube?

Tags: fez

I got the writing cube early on Fez, in a room with jump-mushrooms. When I came back, some golden door-like decorations appeared on a wall. Instead of going there, I went elsewhere first; when I came back that reverted to a normal wall.

I've found no way to go through there: did I permanently miss some content, or was it inactive even before, and that was only a decoration?

*edit*: after wandering randomly in that level, the decoration appeared again, so I *guess* it wasn't lost content after all.

So, is everything ok and supposed to happen this way at this early stage in the game, right?

[image: the golden door frame]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular door is only accessible/visible during night. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I totally didn't think about time of the day!

Comment: This game is freaking awesome.

Comment: @DavidYell It is! I can't name any other game that feels so rewarding when you solve riddles on your own ;)

Comment: @Neon1024 for me it was borderline unplayable 